# How pass an argument rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How pass an argument?

```
<%= link_to "OK", suit_post_path(post), method: :put %>
```

I want pass object post and get in controller

```
def suit

  @post = params[:post]

  @post.suit = true

  if @post.save
    redirect_to tencet_show_path
  end

end
```

I just want change variable of post by clicking.

Or something like

```
<%= link_to_function "OK", "post.suit = true" :post => post %>
```

Comment: Try  `<%= link_to_function "OK",  :post => post.suit %>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an argument, by adding it to the path, like this

```
suit_post_path(post, :suit => true)
```

Also note that in the controller, params is not the Post object, you have to fetch it from the database

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
```